# Create Front-end for azure function

Tags: python, django, azure-functions, frontend

I got several azure functions built in python, like blobTrigger functions or TimerTrigger functions, and I wanted to know if it was possible to create a front end interface for our azure functions to simplify the UX, add boutons etc ... for people who are not familiar with.

I would like to do it with Django to simply trigger a function, drag and drop files ...

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Maybe worth looking into OpenAPI? It provides a UI that you can call relevant functions and group them accordingly etc.
https://medium.com/@ratrosy/building-apis-with-openapi-ac3c24e33ee3